# Slick 3 MySQL Streaming application just hangs... (doesn't stream data)

Tags: scala, slick, akka-stream

```
val enableJdbcStreaming: (java.sql.Statement) => Unit = { statement ⇒
  if (statement.isWrapperFor(classOf[com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl])) {
        statement.unwrap(classOf[com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl]).enableStreamingResults()
  }
}

implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
implicit val actorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()
val config = ConfigFactory.load()
val db = Database.forConfig("mysql")
val query = Tables.Foo.map(r => (r.id, r.pid)).result
val source = Source.fromPublisher[(Long, Option[Long])](db.stream(query.withStatementParameters(statementInit = enableJdbcStreaming)))
val future = source.runForEach(x => println(x))
import actorSystem.distpatcher
future.onComplete{ _ => 
  db.close()
  actorSystem.terminate()
}
Await.result(future, Duration.Inf)
Await.result(actorsystem.whenTerminated, Duration.Inf)
```

Library dependencies

```
"com.lightbend.akka" %% "akka-stream-alpakka-cassandra" % "0.11",
"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.2.1",
"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-hikaricp" % "3.2.1",
"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.44",
"ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3"
```

mysql config

```
mysql {
  profile = "slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile$"
  dataSourceClass = "slick.jdbc.DatabaseUrlDataSource"
  properties {
    driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url  = "jdbc:mysql://server:3306/db"
    user = "user"
    password = "password"
  }
  connectionTimeout = 300
}
```

When I run this code. it just keeps printing these lines on console

```
[info] 19:20:31.647 [mysql housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - mysql - Pool stats (total=21, active=1, idle=20, waiting=0)
[info] 19:21:01.649 [mysql housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - mysql - Pool stats (total=21, active=1, idle=20, waiting=0)
[info] 19:21:31.656 [mysql housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - mysql - Pool stats (total=21, active=1, idle=20, waiting=0)
[info] 19:22:01.661 [mysql housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - mysql - Pool stats (total=21, active=1, idle=20, waiting=0)
[info] 19:22:31.668 [mysql housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - mysql - Pool stats (total=21, active=1, idle=20, waiting=0)
[info] 19:23:01.674 [mysql housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - mysql - Pool stats (total=21, active=1, idle=20, waiting=0)
[info] 19:23:31.680 [mysql housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - mysql - Pool stats (total=21, active=1, idle=20, waiting=0)
[info] 19:24:01.687 [mysql housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - mysql - Pool stats (total=21, active=1, idle=20, waiting=0)
[info] 19:24:31.693 [mysql housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - mysql - Pool stats (total=21, active=1, idle=20, waiting=0)
[info] 19:25:01.699 [mysql housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - mysql - Pool stats (total=21, active=1, idle=20, waiting=0)
[info] 19:25:31.706 [mysql housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - mysql - Pool stats (total=21, active=1, idle=20, waiting=0)
[info] 19:26:01.708 [mysql housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - mysql - Pool stats (total=21, active=1, idle=20, waiting=0)
```

I waited for a long time but it kept on printing these lines.

My expectation was that it will instantly start reading the table row by row for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself. I think I was not building the graph correctly.

I rewrote my graph using the RunnableGraph. and now it works perfectly

```
val query = sql"select id from foo".as[Long]
val publisher = db.stream(query.withStatementParameters(statementInit = enableJdbcStreaming))
val source = Source.fromPublisher[Long](publisher)
val sink = Sink.foreach[Long]{x => println(x)}
val graph = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(sink){implicit b => s =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._
  source ~> s.in
  ClosedShape
})
val future = graph.run()
Await.result(future, Duration.Inf)
```

Although it will be interesting to know why did the previous approach did not work.